# JavaFX creating a new scene from KeyCombination correctly

Tags: model-view-controller, javafx, scene

I dont like menu bars so I am limiting my application to KeyCombinations to spawn events. I have the key combination working however I have a feeling I am not using controllers correctly. I need to edit the new scene within my controller but instead I find myself doing so within the try/catch of the KeyCombination event.

I would like to make all changes to the scene in class SettingsController.java

**where I create a new scene/view**

```
final KeyCombination settingsCMD = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (settingsCMD.match(event))
        {
            System.out.println("CTRL + S was pressed on " + name + " display\n" +
                    "Opening Settings Scene");
            /*
             *  This is where we need to launch a scene for settings
             */
            try
            {
                Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/view/settingsscreen.fxml"));
                Stage settingsStage = new Stage();
                settingsStage.setTitle("Settings");
                settingsStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500 , 400));
                settingsStage.show();

                // This really needs to be done in the controller. How do I do this?
                JSON jsonTools = new JSON();
                jsonTools.readJSONSettings();
                jsonTools.writeJSONSettings();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**SettingsController.java**

```
public class SettingsController
{

    @FXML private TextField hostname;


    public String getText()
    {
        String textProp = textProperty().get();
        System.out.println("testProperty is " + textProp + "\n");
        return textProp;
    }

    public void setText(String value)
    {
        textProperty().set(value);
    }

    private StringProperty textProperty()
    {
        return hostname.textProperty();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to the view controller class from the `FXMLLoader`:

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
    Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
    parentStage.setScene(scene);

    Controller controller = loader.getController();
```

On this reference you can call the appropriate method

```
final KeyCombination settingsCMD = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (settingsCMD.match(event))
        {
            System.out.println("CTRL + S was pressed on " + name + " display\n" +
                    "Opening Settings Scene");
            /*
             *  This is where we need to launch a scene for settings
             */
            try
            {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/view/settingsscreen.fxml"));
                Parent root = loader.load();
                SettingsController controller = loader.getController();

                Stage settingsStage = new Stage();
                settingsStage.setTitle("Settings");
                settingsStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500 , 400));
                settingsStage.show();

                controller.yourMethod();

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have been moving this block all over my code to get this working, could you please place it within the provided code so I understand what you are doing?

Comment: Maybe this answer can provide you some additional help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585761/store-dynamic-screen-with-multiple-stages/36612093#36612093](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585761/store-dynamic-screen-with-multiple-stages/36612093#36612093).