# How to create two controller for two different fxml files in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to open a new window after a button click and close the previouse one.
For both windows I want to have different .fxml files and controller classes for its.

I show you how I design it:

1. From main class firstPanelController.class is run

   ```
   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           Application.launch(LoginPanelController.class, args);
       }       
   }
   ```
2. In FirstPanel class the primary stage is created and then after button click ( goToMainPanel() method) I want to show new window with different controller class.

   ```
   public class FirstPanelController extends Application implements Initializable  {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       try {
           Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FirstPanel.fxml"));
           Scene scene = new Scene(root);
           scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
           primaryStage.setScene(scene);
           primaryStage.show();
       } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }       
   }

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
   }

   @FXML
   private void goToMainPanel(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
       new MainPanelController(Stage stage, Parent root);
   }   
   }
   ```

This is MainPanelController.class:

```
public class MainPanelController implements Initializable {

private Stage stage;
private Parent root;    

public MainPanelController(Stage stage, Parent root) throws IOException {
    stage = this.stage;
    root = this.root;
    root = FXMLLoader().load(getClass().getResource("MainPanel.fxml"))
}


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
}
```

For fxml files I'm using Scene Builder. The controller in firstPanel.fxml is set to firstPanel class and for mainPanel.fxml controoler is set to MainPanel class.

This code doesn't work for me. There is a problem with initialize new controller for mainpanel.fxml file.

Do you see what is wrong in my code ? Maybe you know some better way for having few .fxml files with its own controllers ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585761/store-dynamic-screen-with-multiple-stages/36612093#36612093

Comment: a) passing a variable declaration to  a constructor (or any method call) is invalid syntax b) IMHO a controller class shouldn't extend `Application` to improve reuseability.